# How to download a whole directory with wget ignoring index.xml?

Tags: linux, shell, wget

I am going to download a whole directory from a web server like this:

```
wget -r -nH https://something.com/blah/
```

But there is an index.xml under /blah/, which doesn't have correct hrefs to the files I want to download.

As a result, when I launch the `wget` command above, it only downloads the index.xml and stops.

I can't modify or delete the index.xml file because /blah/ isn't owned by me.

Are there any workarounds to allow me to download the whole directory, ignoring what index.xml suggests?

Answer (score 1):

From `man wget`:

```
Recursive Accept/Reject Options
   -A acclist --accept acclist
   -R rejlist --reject rejlist
     Specify comma-separated lists of file name suffixes or patterns to accept
     or reject. Note that if any of the wildcard characters, *, ?, [ or ], appear
     in an element of acclist or rejlist, it will be treated as a pattern, rather
     than a suffix.
```

Thus `--reject xml` should fix your problem.

Comment: Won't `--reject xml` reject any file with an `.xml` suffix, not just the specific `index.xml` file the OP wants to exclude?

Comment: Yep, but if that's a problem it's easily adapted to `index.xml` instead isn't it?

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear - downloading index.(xml/html) seems to be the default behavior of wget. Wget needs to figure out which files need to download from it. So no matter whether I specify --reject index.xml or not, it is always downloaded, and other files still aren't downloaded. Besides, --reject index.xml still downloads index.xml, but delete it from local.